# Stuck trying to upgrade Ubuntu Sever 19.10 to 20.04. Window detachment?

Tags: server, upgrade

As the title says, I'm trying upgrade my server. I run `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it seems to run smoothly until possibly after "Reading state information... Done"; where it says No candidate ver for several linux-modules-5.3.0-x-generic and several linux-modules-extra-5.0.3-x-generic.

However, it continues going after those messages, so that may be totally unrelated. After that it updates repo information from focal, and seems to be successful until "Calculating the changes" where it says `=== Command detached from window (the current time) ===` followed after about 10 seconds by `=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (the current time) ===`.

At this point nothing will happen until I press a key, and I'm presented with the prompt `Press x to destroy or r to resurrect window`. If I press x, I'm dumped back to the terminal, and if I press r, it appears to just restart the process, going back to the "Reading cache" step.